# Implications of flushing stdout after each print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script whose output is piped to `less`, and I would like the script to print it's statements into `less` as they come, rather than all at once.

I found that if I flush stdout (via `sys.stdout.flush()`) after each print, the line is displayed in `less` when flushed (obviously).

My question is: Are there any drawbacks to doing this? My script has hundreds of thousands of lines being printed, would flushing **after each line** cause problems?

My impression is yes, because you take extra resources up for displaying each time you flush, as well as completely circumventing the idea of buffered output

Comment: Python can be told to automatically flush everything. I'd consider taking advantage of that instead of making your code longer.

Comment: See the `-u` argument to the Python interpreter, and the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable; both are documented at https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it!

Comment: If you're emitting hundreds of thousands of lines, by the way, I'm surprised you aren't filling up the buffer (which is typically something like 8K-32K) and flushing earlier even without needing to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the only drawback is that it's potentially slower.  The buffering on stdin allows your program to run ahead of the physical I/O which is slow.

However, if you're sending it to less, you're operating at human speeds anyway -- it's not going to make a difference.

Comment: Unless the user is using `less` in a tailing mode, the tool isn't needing to print everything until the user scrolls down to see it, so by forcing the program to write to `less` in smaller chunks, you're decreasing total throughput. Maybe not by much, but I don't find the argument made here (that use of a program that spools output to the user means that the speed of writing that output into the program is moot) compelling; if the user is just going to search that output for errors (using `/` or similar facilities) rather than reading every line at human speed, total throughput matters.

Comment: Not by much, probably not even perceptibly.

Comment: Depends on the details, as in all things. I could probably construct a pathological case where it mattered -- if you were spooling to a filesystem mounted with the sync flag, maybe, or if the system were already bogging down under interrupt load -- but granted, those are corner case scenarios.